# Swift receiving javascript messages don't work

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I need that javascript send a message for swift but don't work.

The Swift Code:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {

@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
     print( "Enter here" )

    if message.name == "jsHandler" {
        print( message.body );
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "web")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let user = WKUserContentController()
    user.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
    webview.configuration.userContentController = user

    webview.uiDelegate = self
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
    webview.load(request)
}
```

The javascript code:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.element', function() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage( "Invoke swift" );
} );
```

Is something wrong or something missing?

Comment: I found the solution and I will post the answer above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I don't know if it's the better way but solved for me.

Thw wkwebview needs a configuration when it start so it can't be created with the graphic view. I created it by code.

```
//@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!
var wk: WKWebView!
```

Inside viewDidLoad function:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let user = WKUserContentController()

user.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
config.userContentController = user

wk = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
view.addSubview(wk)

let layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

wk.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
wk.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
wk.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
wk.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
wk.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

So it's possible javascript send messages for Swift!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Storyboard just set in viewDidLoad **before webview.load(request)**

```
//webview is your @IBOutlet
webview.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "yourHandler")
webview.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
```